# specify directories architecture skip one level

Tags: regex, shell, unix, directory, command

the directories looks like `./2012/NY/M/` `./2012/NJ/F/` and `.etc`

I'd like to find all files under `/f` no matter which state it is in

How should I write?

I tried `./2012/*/F` but it does not work...

Comment: "does not work" is useless as a problem description. What did you see and what did you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

`./2012/*/F` should return you all the directories no matter the state.

If you want the files under that, you've got to glob for them too: `./2012/*/F/*`

Comment: what if I don't want to use wildcard and substitute it with './2012/*/F'? Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Your solution is already using a wildcard. What's your real constraint? As for why it doesn't work, well that's just how globbing works: it returns the list of pathnames that match the string. The strings ends in `/F`, whereas the files under there don't.

Comment: Thanks! So I tried find './2012/*/F/*' but it still doesn't work, how this comes?

Comment: I'm going with @glennjackman's advice here. “Does not work” is not a problem description. Update your question with what you tried, what it did, and why you think that's not what it should have done.