# Add and Sort numbers in files

Tags: regex, shell, unix, command

I have directories like

```
./2012/NY/F/ 
./2012/NJ/M/ 
....
```

Under these directories, there are files with names like `Zoe` etc...

Each file contains a number.

I'd like to sum the numbers in the file with same file name in different directories and find the max of sum, how should I write?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that your `./2012/NY/F`, `/2012/sfs/XXS` all under directory, say, `/home/yourusername/data/`,

You can try this if you are using *nix or if you have cygwin installed on your windows

```
    cd /home/yourusername/data ; find ./ -name yourfile_name_to_lookup.txt | xargs awk 'BEGIN {sum=0} ; {sum+=$1} ; END {print sum} '
```

I assume the number starting from the first column in that file (`$1`).

Comment: how to write parent_dir here? could you please give me a way without using wildcard (for exercise purpose)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To locate the files, use a glob such as specified in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18966457/specify-directories-architecture-skip-one-level).

To do the actual summing, there are quite a few possibilities depending on the number of files and range of the numbers, but a reasonably general-purpose way would be with awk:

```
awk '{sum += $1} END { print sum }' file1 file2 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the unique names of the files and the file names don't have space in them, then following may work.

```
cd 2012/
for i in "Zoe" "file2" "file3"
do 
  k=$(cat $(find . -type f -name "$i")); 
  echo $k | awk '{for(i=t=0;i<NF;) t+=$++i; $0=t}1';
done | sort -r
```

This will sum up files with same names from subdirs under `2012` and `sort -r` will return the numbers in max to min order.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the entire contents of the file is a number. I assume that the number is an integer. Requires bash 4 for the associative array

```
declare -A sum_for_file
for path in ./2012/*/*/*; do
    (( sum_for_file["$(basename "$path")"] += $(< "$path") ))
done

max=0
for file in "${!sum_for_file[@]}"; do
    if (( ${sum_for_file["$file"]} > max )); then
        max=${sum_for_file["$file"]}
        maxfile=$file
    fi
    # you didn't say you needed to print it, but if you do
    printf "%d\t%s\n" ${sum_for_file["$file"]} "$file"
done

echo "the maximum sum is $max found in files named $maxfile"
```